# What does "wipe" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

A guy sells MacBooks on eBay, and here is the email he sent me regarding my questions. The part that I do not understand is in bold.

> That is what I do for this business is sell used macbooks. We buy these in large quantities and **wipe them**, load new operating system and sell them. The battery is good, this unit does have some imperfections that we have either pictured or described in the listing. Please read entire listing to make sure you know what you are buying. As for shipping it is @ 70.00 shipping to you.

Does "wipe" mean "to refurbish"?

Comment: Note that the English in this example is poor, though **wipe** is used in a standard sense when talking about computers.

Comment: Does "wipe" means to *refurbish*? No, it means to erase / delete / remove data from a hard disc.

Answer (score 18):

It could mean that the data is erased, or it could imply a more thorough erasure.

The [*Hacking Lexicon*](http://www.linuxsecurity.com/resource_files/documentation/hacking-dict.html#wipe) mentions:

> Erased data can frequently be retrieved through forensics on the magnetic material of a hard-disk drive or backup tape. So-called "magnetoresistive microscopes" have been developed that painstakingly scour magnetic media, and are able to reconstruct the magnetic image of a disk surface. This will show the faint residue of overwritten data. A common security measure is to "wipe" all traces of the data from a machine. **The wiping process usually involves**:
>
> - **Clearing caches and logfiles**. Example include browser caches, cookie files, history logs, and recently used document lists. Note that passwords are often stored in cookies and history URLs.
> - Hard-disks "erase" files by simply removing their entries from the directory. The files still exist on the hard-disk. The first step of wiping is to actually erase them by **overwriting** that area of **the disk**.
> - **Overwriting erased areas of the hard-disk** at least 7-times (DoD spec) in order to remove all magnetic traces. Forensics specialists can usually read data from a disk that has been overwritten only once.
> - **Wiping the pagefile**. Most programs do this by repeated allocating all possible memory in the system then freeing it, multiple times.

So the true meaning of *wipe* in the text that you cite might depend on who wrote the sentence – was it authored by a marketer, or a technician? A marketer might use the word *wipe* even if the company only performs a simple erasure of data on the refurbished hard drives, implying some of the old data could still be read with some sophisticated retrieval techniques.  (Or sometimes files just get left on [inadvertently](http://www.neowin.net/news/woman-finds-pics-of-nude-dudes-on-her-new-phone).) However, perhaps the company is more careful than that, and the data is meticulously overwritten with 1's and 0's multiple times to prevent any of it from being readable again, even through [computer forensics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_forensics#Techniques).

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, **wipe** here means, removing all the content in the macbook (like files, folders, operating system, etc) and then installing new operating system.

Comment: You could improve this answer by doing a little research to substantiate your "according to me" claim. For example, looking up _wipe_ on [OneLook](http://www.onelook.com/?w=wipe&ls=a) shows that [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/wipe#wipe_17) lists one meaning as "to remove information from a tape, video, or computer disk" and also provides a link to a [computing dictionary](http://www.linuxsecurity.com/resource_files/documentation/hacking-dict.html#wipe) which reads: _A common security measure is to "wipe" all traces of the data from a machine._

Comment: I know about it. But there is no single right answer for questions like these. It is the perspective. Like you said, if looking up in OneLook gave you this meaning, likewise looking up in some other source would give you a bit different meaning. My answer was my perspective, which i cannot claim to be 100% sure. That is why you see "According to me" in my answer (most of my answers). PS: This is a friendly reply to your comment. :)

Comment: You and I agree, then – the word _wipe_ might not always mean the same thing. That's why [my answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/44302/what-does-wipe-means-here/44312#44312) delves into a little more detail. In general, the Stack Exchange discourages opinion-based questions (questions can even be closed if they are deemed "primarily opinion-based"). Therefore, it's usually best to support your answers, either by citing some credible source, or by giving more than one possible interpretation. Otherwise, how is anyone to know if your answer is trustworthy, or a mere guess?

Comment: P.S. I'm trying to be friendly here as well – thanks for your positive attitude :^)

Comment: Not sure of the value of answers that start off "In my opinion".  It makes Stack Exchange not a very useful reference.  I really believe that if you're not sure of the answer, you shouldn't be posting it.

Comment: @DavidWallace - To be fair to the O.P., I added the words "in my opinion" in an edit. However, the original read "according to me", which I assumed was meant to convey "this is what I think". I don't think it reads very well as "according to me", but the O.P. seems to [like that wording](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/36905/what-does-imaginative-consciousness-mean/44146#44146), though.

Comment: @J.R. Thanks for clarifying that "in my opinion" was your edit.  I had missed that detail.  However, "according to me" suffers from the same problem as "in my opinion"; unless the respondent happens himself to be a reputable source.  His comment that includes the words "...  i cannot claim to be 100% sure ..." suggests that this is not the case.  I am strongly opposed to "guesses" appearing as answers on any stack exchange site, and I usually apply downvotes liberally in such cases.

Comment: @DavidWallace - Actually, I'm appreciating your comments; they show I'm not some lone curmudgeon who needs to take some Xanax or something. And even if this answer doesn't get improved, exhortations are often good for subsequent answers. Hopefully the future will have more nuggets like, _"According to Oxford..."_, or, _"According to Webster..."_, and fewer that say, _"According to me..."_.